# Game theory, gambling odds

Tags: game-theory

I'm looking for mathematics around such game:

Two games:

```
50%, max bet: 155000, price x1.96
0.0015%, max bet: 5, price x64224.3
```

Let, I will place 155,000 for 50% and win only 303,800. Or place 31000 other bids with only 5 coins in each for 0.0015%, and win 321,121, What is probability?

Each game may give me coins. E.g. I can win every 31,000, my win will be 9,954,766,500.0 (Oh, my god 9 billions)

Or only 2 games from 31,000 and win 642243.0 ( Twice more than first variant ).

What is the probabilities for multiple games? Should I sum it or should I calculate anything else?

Comment: Please write out the rules of the games clearly.  It sounds like the first has a $50\%$ chance of winning and returns $1.96$ times your bet if you win, $0$ if you lose.  Is that correct?  Then it is not at all clear what you are asking.

Comment: In the reality it returns 0.01, to keep user friendly mode may be...

Comment: @Ross Millikan, Are you mention 31,000 * 0.01 = 310 coins?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the rules correctly, the first game on average returns $\frac 12 \cdot 1.96+ \frac 12 \cdot 0.01 =0.985$ of your bet, so on average you lose $1.5\%$ of your bet.  The second returns $1.5 \cdot 10^{-5} \cdot 64224.3 \approx 96.3\%$ of your bet.  Both are losing propositions.

Comment: Could you be more verbose, what is 10^-5 ?

Comment: $1.5\cdot 10^{-5}=0.0015\%$ is the probability of winning the second bet

Comment: 1.5 * 10^(-5) = 0.000015 %. 5 zeroes. The second bet prob. is 1.5 * 10^(-3) = 0.0015%.

Comment: The percent sign accounts for the other two zeros.

Comment: Ok, thanks. But I'm asking about other wins, look, first game - only one transactions, the second variant is a 31k transactions, there is chance to win each 31k game.

Comment: I still don't understand the question you are asking.  If you want the probability of winning a given number of times out of all the bets you make, it is the [binomial distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution)